# Coverflow with custom layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, coverflow

[image]

I want coverflow with the layout that i given above. i tried several famous link of coverflow but they are only for the imageview, i can not make my layout to that coverflow.

So any suggestions of link to achieve this layout in to the coverflow in android?

Any answer or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can download the code from the link 

https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/ and modify the same to your requirements

Comment: can you give adapter file for it?

Comment: Since you don't say what libraries you've tried, it's hard to recommend one you haven't tried.

Comment: I have used the same from google code: http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow

Comment: @RushabhPatel: If you have got the solution for the same then it would be great if you share the solution.